# Alien girl comes to the Earth to find 3 keys, chased by 3 alien guys all along

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv

When I was in kindergarten I watched a British kids TV show about an alien girl who landed on Earth and was helped by 3 local kids to find the 3 keys she needed to save her dad on her planet. The girl could only eat these orange pills she carried in a funny box, and she was also chased all along by 3 scary-looking guys, who were her dad's enemies.

Do you know the name of the TV show by any chance?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_the_Lost_Keys?

Comment: When were you in kindergarten?

Comment: I did not go to kindergarten in the UK but since this series was on the back of a video tape with Big Muzzy I presumed it is also British.                                       

Sadly it is not The Legend of the Lost Keys.